# Pointer of a character in C++

Tags: c++

Going by the books, the first cout line should print me the address of the location where the **char variable b** is stored, which seems to be the case for the **int variable a** too. But the first cout statement prints out an odd **'dh^#'** while the second statement correctly prints a hex value **'
ox23fd68'**. Why is this happening?

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        char b='d';
        int a=10;
        char *c=new char[10];
        c=&b;
        int *e=&a;
        cout<<"c: "<<c<<endl;
        cout<<"e: "<<e;
    }
```

Comment: hint: "by the books" should `"c: "` print an address too?

Comment: This is not a bad question, but probably answered elsewhere.  The short answer is that C++ has inherited C's treatment of `char *` as "Probably a collection of printable things".

Comment: From what books did you get this idea?

Comment: If this is what your book is teaching you, please throw it out and try something off [The Book List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: I'd be more inclined to think the OP was going by the book, and then extrapolated what they had learned, only to find out, that `char*` are handled differently from all other pointer types. As common as it may be to those that have seen C-style strings all of their (developer) lives, this can be justified as *surprising*.

Comment: The author explains pointers with an example of an integer variable and says it works the same for every other data type. I guess it's a lack of thoroughness. Thank you for your suggestions anyway. :)

Comment: @DrewDormann: Best way I've heard it put in a long time :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this program has problem. There is a memory leak.

```
char *c=new char[10];
c=&b;
```

This allocates 10 characters on heap, but then the pointer to heap is overwritten with the address of the variable `b`.

When a `char*` is written to `cout` with `operator<<` then it is considered as a null terminated C-string. As the address of b was initialized to a single character containing `d` `op<<` continues to search on the stack finding the first null character. It seems the it was found after a few characters, so `dh^#` is written (the `d` is the value of variable `b` the rest is just some random characters found on the stack before the 1st `\0` char).

If you want to get the address try to use `static_cast<void*>(c)`.

My example:

```
int main() {
  char *c;
  char b = 'd';
  c = &b; 
  cout << c << ", " << static_cast<void*>(c) << endl;
}
```

An the output:

```
dÌÿÿ, 0xffffcc07
```

See the strange characters after 'd'.

I hope this could help a bit!

Answer (score 5):

There is a non-member overload [operator<<(std::basic_ostream)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) for the `const char*` type, that doesn't write the address, but rather the (presumed) C-style string<sup>1)</sup>. In your case, since you have assigned the address of a single character, there is no `NUL` terminator, and thus no valid C-style string. The code exhibits [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

The behavior for `int*` is different, as there is no special handling for pointers to `int`, and the statement writes the address to the stream, as expected.

If you want to get the address of the character instead, use a `static_cast`:

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>( c ) << std::endl;
```

---

<sup>1)</sup> *A C-style string is a sequence of characters, terminated by a `NUL` character (`'\0'`).*